# Lucene.Net phrase count

Tags: lucene.net

As with Lucene.net count how many times the **phrase** is met (**not the *word* "something", namely the *phrase* "Hi how are you"**) in the text?

*I sorry for my English.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to use [TermPositionVectors](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/TermPositionVector.html).

You basically get the positions for each of your query terms, and count the number of times they occur in the same order in your Document as they were in your Query.

Comment: **Thank you very much for your response! :)**
Sorry, but it does not fit, TermPositionVector splits by **words**.

String = "test bad word bad test bad word bad"
Reply from TermPositionVector: {contents: bad / 4, test / 2, word / 2}

I need to split the phrase **"bad word"** or **"bad test"**, and that would have been a response from Lucene.Net:
"bad word" : "met two times in the text"
"bad test" : "met one times in the text"

Comment: i know TermPositionVector is by words, but if you have the positions for each Term, you can certainly find and count the phrases in your document. Look into IndexesOf() and GetTermPositions() methods. I know you can do it because I did it in the past but I dont have the code available to post a sample.